# Callbacks not called in Azure mobile services shared scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, callback, azure-mobile-services

After refactoring some of our scripts and putting some functions in separate custom modules in shared folder, I had encountered a very strange problem. Don't even know how to describe it properly. Think best way is to show it by an example. I apologise in advance, for long portions of code I will post here. I just don't know how else I can explain my problem.

We have several shared scripts with some of our common functional:

`shared/commons-util.js` - several convenient utility functions, among them is this one:

```
function getErrorHandler(errMessage, callback) {
  return function(err) {
    console.log('inside error handler')
    console.error(errMessage + '\nCause: ', err)
    if (callback instanceof Function) {
      callback(err)
    }
  }
}

exports.getErrorHandler = getErrorHandler
```

`shared/commons-db.js` - helper functions for working with database tables:

```
var waitingTime = +process.env.throttlingWaitTime || 0;
var retryCount = +process.env.throttlingRetryCount || 0;

function refreshThrottlingLimit() {
  var throttlingLimit = +process.env.throttlingLimit || 0
  if (LMD_GLOBALS.throttling.limit != throttlingLimit) {
    LMD_GLOBALS.throttling.available += throttlingLimit - LMD_GLOBALS.throttling.limit
    LMD_GLOBALS.throttling.limit = throttlingLimit
  }
}

function throttledWrite(operation, table, data, callbacks, retriesLeft) {
  refreshThrottlingLimit()
  if (LMD_GLOBALS.throttling.limit && LMD_GLOBALS.throttling.available > 0) {
    LMD_GLOBALS.throttling.available--

    try {
      console.log('Executing ' + operation + ' on table: ' + table.getTableName() + ', data: ', data, 'callbacks: ', callbacks)

      table[operation](data, {
        success: function(result) {
          try {
            console.log('throttledWrite: SUCCESS')
            LMD_GLOBALS.throttling.available++
            if (callbacks && callbacks.success) callbacks.success(result)
          } catch (e) {
            console.error('Exception in success callback', e)
          }
        },
        error: function(err) {
          try {
            console.log('throttledWrite: ERROR')
            LMD_GLOBALS.throttling.available++
            err.table = table.getTableName()
            err.operation = operation
            err.data = data
            if (callbacks && callbacks.error) callbacks.error(err)
          } catch (e) {
            console.error('Exception in error callback', e)
          }
        }
      })

      console.log(operation + ' started...')
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Exception starting ' + operation, e)
    }
  } else if (retriesLeft > 0) {
    setTimeout(throttledWrite, waitingTime, operation, table, data, callbacks, retriesLeft - 1)
  } else {
    if (callbacks && callbacks.error) callbacks.error(new Error('Aborting ' + operation + ' operation (waited for too long)'))
  }
}

exports.throttledInsert = function(table, data, callbacks) {
  throttledWrite('insert', table, data, callbacks, retryCount)
}
exports.throttledUpdate = function(table, data, callbacks) {
  throttledWrite('update', table, data, callbacks, retryCount)
}
```

`shared/commons.js` - Just combining this two modules:

```
exports.db = require('../shared/commons-db.js')
exports.util = require('../shared/commons-util.js')
```

We are using this modules in scheduled script `executeBackgroundJobs.js`:

```
var commons = require('../shared/commons.js');

// Same high-order function as in `commons-util.js`. Only difference is that it is defined locally, not in the separate module.
function getErrorHandler(errMessage, callback) {
  return function(err) {
    console.log('inside error handler')
    console.error(errMessage + '\nCause: ', err)
    if (callback instanceof Function) {
      callback(err)
    }
  }
}

function executeBackgroundJobs() {
  test();
}

function test() {
  console.log('Testing paranormal activity in Azure');

  var testTable = tables.getTable('test');

  var callback = function(res) {
    console.log('Test OK', res)
  }

  var errMessage = 'Could not write to `test` table';

  var errHandler_1 = commons.util.getErrorHandler(errMessage, callback); // First handler we get from high-order function from custom module
  var errHandler_2 = getErrorHandler(errMessage, callback); // Second handler must be the same, just getting from local function not from the external module

  // This log lines just show that this two functions are identical
  console.log('errHandler_1: ', errHandler_1);
  console.log('errHandler_2: ', errHandler_2);

  // We are calling `throttledUpdate` two times with two different error handlers for each invocation

  commons.db.throttledUpdate(testTable, {
    id: 'test-01',  // Data object is intentionally illegal, we want update to fail
    someColumn: 'some value #1'
  }, {
    success: callback,
    error: errHandler_1
  });

  commons.db.throttledUpdate(testTable, {
    id: 'test-02',  // Data object is intentionally illegal, we want update to fail
    someColumn: 'some value #2'
  }, {
    success: callback,
    error: errHandler_2
  });

}
```

Now here's the output of the one invocation of this job:

1: First call of `throttledWrite`:

```
INFORMATION:
Executing update on table: test, data:  { id: 'test-01', someColumn: 'some value #1' } callbacks:  { success: [Function], error: [Function] }
```

2: Start of the `test()`. It is already strange that logs are not in proper order, cause this functions so far are called synchronously (or at least I believe so). Does this mean that logging in Azure is happening in different threads? Anyway, this is not our main problem.

```
INFORMATION:
Testing paranormal activity in Azure
```

3: Here we just show the body of first handler

```
INFORMATION:
errHandler_1:  function (err) {
    console.log('inside error handler')
    console.error(errMessage + '\nCause: ', err)
    if (callback instanceof Function) {
      callback(err)
    }
  }
```

4: Here we just show the body of second handler

```
INFORMATION:
errHandler_2:  function (err) {
    console.log('inside error handler')
    console.error(errMessage + '\nCause: ', err)
    if (callback instanceof Function) {
      callback(err)
    }
  }
```

5: `table.update` method was launched successfully in the first `throttledWrite` (no exceptions)

```
INFORMATION:
update started...
```

6: Second call of `throttledWrite`:

```
INFORMATION:
Executing update on table: test, data:  { id: 'test-02', someColumn: 'some value #2' } callbacks:  { success: [Function], error: [Function] }
```

7: `table.update` method was launched successfully in the second `throttledWrite` (no exceptions)

```
INFORMATION:
update started...
```

9: Error handler was called

```
INFORMATION:
inside error handler
```

10: From **only** the second `throttledWrite`

```
ERROR:
Could not write to `test` table
Cause:  { _super: undefined,
  message: 'Could not save item because it contains a column that is not in the table schema.',
  code: 'BadInput',
  table: 'test',
  operation: 'update',
  data: { id: 'test-02', someColumn: 'some value #2' } }
```

11: And that's all

```
INFORMATION:
Test OK { _super: undefined,
  message: 'Could not save item because it contains a column that is not in the table schema.',
  code: 'BadInput',
  table: 'test',
  operation: 'update',
  data: { id: 'test-02', someColumn: 'some value #2' } }
```

First of all the strangest thing I cannot understand is why there was no callback invoked in first `throttledWrite` call.

And besides that, even in the second `throttledWrite`, where callback was called, no log was written from `table.update`-s `error` callback. Remember this lines from `throttledWrite` function:

```
        error: function(err) {
          try {
            console.log('throttledWrite: ERROR')
            LMD_GLOBALS.throttling.available++
            err.table = table.getTableName()
            err.operation = operation
            err.data = data
            if (callbacks && callbacks.error) callbacks.error(err)
          } catch (e) {
            console.error('Exception in error callback', e)
          }
        }
```

I have to add that this is not the actual code where I first encountered this problems. I tried to shorten code before posting. So you may don't fully understand the purposes of some methods. It does not matter, this code is just for demonstration.

That's it. I have three mysteries that I cannot explain:

1. Why callbacks are not called (in first case)?
2. Why did `console.log('throttledWrite: ERROR')` not write anything in log (when I am sure, it was called and was successful)?
3. Less critical, but still interesting, why are logs not in proper order?